# Parent model with multiple child records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model

This seems like such a basic concept, but for some reason, its completely eluding me.

Parent Model

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Child> Children { get; set; }  <-- removed this line
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }        <-- added this line
}
```

Child model

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string SomeStringVar { get; set; }
}
```

I thought by simply running

```
var parents = _context.Parents.Include(c => c.Children).ToList();
```

would return a list of all parents with all associated children for each one, but the lambda expressions errors out with the error `Cannot convert the lambda expression to type string`.

Like I say, I am SURE its something basic, but dang if I can figure it out.

Suggestions?

Comment: `using System.Data.Entity;` ?

Comment: Doh!  Added the using statement and that cleared it up.  However, I did need to change my model as indicated in the edit above in order for this to work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Parent class must have Children as a List of Child not IQueryable

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```